# Remove Github Actions from Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, adware, visual-studio-2022

With the latest update of Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.7.0 Preview 4.0), I now have an seemingly non-removable node in Solution Explorer with the Github logo labeled 'Github Actions'.

It's not the end of the world, but it becomes one more thing that I don't use that further clutters up the already cluttered UI.  My repository isn't even hosted on Github, so it's completely pointless.  It seems like it's just more adware for Microsoft.

Can it be removed?  Is it somehow really useful for even non-Github users, and I'm just missing the point?

**More:**

Some additional info.  I have a folder that has been placed in my solution folder called `.github` - It contains one empty folder called `workflows`.  I can delete it, but it returns at some point always.

Further - inside my .git folder, there is a file called `ms-persist.xml`.  I didn't add that file, and I've never seen it before.  These are the contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PendingCommit>
  <CommitComment />
  <WorkItems />
  <PinnedBranches />
  <PublishPrompt Enabled="True" />
  <RepositorySorts />
</PendingCommit>
```

I'm hesitant to mess with it without knowing what it is and what the implications might be.  But if anyone knows, by all means.

Comment: Check menu *Tools > Options > Preview Features > GitHub Actions support in Publish*, if this can be disabled. If this option has been moved elsewhere, search Options for "GitHub Actions".

Comment: Only thing with github in options is `Include Github Enterprise Server Accounts`  under accounts, and `Github issue and pull request auto-completions`  under "Preview Features."  Both are unchecked

Comment: It seems that this was removed from Options, so was only available when GitHub Actions was introduced initially and has now become unconditional.

Comment: @harrymc - see my update - maybe it will reveal something

Comment: Sorry, I don't see there anything useful.

Comment: Someone already shared [feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Remove-Github-actions-from-solution-expl/10433404) on this over at MS dev community to implement an option to disable this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, it wasn't intentional this node showed up for all solutions. A MSFT employee stated:

> - VS 17.8 Preview 2 includes a fix that stops the new node from showing up when the repo is not hosted on github.com (untested).
> - VS 17.7.1 will also include that same fix (further posts suggest it was actually only released in VS 17.7.2 as of Aug 22nd, 2023).
> - We are also working on a new entry under Tools > Options that turns the node off completely, even for repos hosted on github.com, to be
>   expected in "soon after".

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Remove-Github-actions-from-solution-expl/10433404#T-N10443887

Comment: Interesting.  I just updated to 17.7.3, and I'm having the opposite problem - I have a repo with GitHub actions, but I am not seeing the expected node in Solution Explorer, nor am I seeing an option to enable it.  Microsoft, you're such a tease.

Comment: @MikeLoux Did you ever see the node in any older version, or did you come from a version that didn't have them yet?

Comment: I updated from 17.6.something-or-other, so guessing I came from a version that didn't have them yet.